# In GDB, how do I run a built-in command from a user defined command

Tags: gdb

Using gdb, I need to run extra commands right before `continue` and immediately after it breaks. I thought I would make a user defined command like so:

```
define continue
    pre_continue
    continue
    post_continue
end
```

This, of course, fails in a bottomless recursive pit. Is there a way to call the built-in command directly, bypassing the user defined command?

BTW: I need the command to be named `continue` so that the gdb frontend I'm using will call my user defined function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[User-defined Command Hooks](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Hooks) is what you are looking for:

> You may define hooks, which are a special kind of user-defined
>   command. Whenever you run the command `foo', if the user-defined
>   command`hook-foo' exists, it is executed (with no arguments) before
>   that command.
>
> A hook may also be defined which is run after the command you
>   executed. Whenever you run the command `foo', if the user-defined
>   command`hookpost-foo' exists, it is executed (with no arguments)
>   after that command. Post-execution hooks may exist simultaneously with
>   pre-execution hooks, for the same command.

This solution should work for you:

```
define hook-continue
pre_continue
end

define hookpost-continue
post_continue
end
```

Comment: Just the thing I was looking for! Great. Thanks. I would upvote your answer, but I haven't got a high enough reputation :-)

Comment: This actually only addresses a subset of situations of OP. What if one wants to use the arguments given to continue in the pre_continue or post_continue. Likewise, what if you only conditionally want continue to execute? You could cause an error in the pre-hook, but that will stop the whole script.